# Loop to check time in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datetime, loops, while-loop

So I'm kind of new to VB and am just playing around with a little project, I currently need a loop that is constantly checking the systems clock to see if it's equal to a certain time.

```
   While Not myTime.Hour = 24

        If TimeOfDay = newTime Then
            nfi.ShowBalloonTip(15)
            intRandNumb = RandomNumber(1, 15)
            dblAddMinutes = intTime + intRandNumb
            newTime = TimeOfDay.AddMinutes(dblAddMinutes)

        End If
    End While
```

I have this right now, but obviously it's grinding everything to a halt and using 50% of my cpu in the process, I just would like to know what I can substitute in or change to make this loop run better and perform how I need it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Joel pointed out, you should try using a timer instead. I'm not sure if your app is a form or console or other, so I'll try to be generic and use `System.Timers.Timer`.

The code here (interval is set at 10ms, change to a value of your need):

```
Private timer1 As System.Timers.Timer    
Const interval As Integer = 10 


Sub initTimer()
    timer1 = New System.Timers.Timer(10)
    AddHandler timer1.Elapsed, AddressOf Me.timer_Elapsed
    timer1.Start()
End Sub

Sub timer_Elapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
    'do your stuff here
    'Console.WriteLine(e.SignalTime.ToString())
End Sub
```

Comment: OOps, I didn't realise Grizzly did a sample. Mine is VB though. I'm a C#-er, so took me awhile to get the codes out.

Comment: Thanks for your time, it really helped and everything is running smoothly now.

Answer (score 1):

you can add

```
Threading.Thread.Sleep(0),
```

this will cause a context switch and greatly reduce the CPU usage

Also consider using a timer object to be called every 10 or 100 ms, this will also be better in usage then having a loop

Comment: I've never used a timer object before how would I go about implementing one in this case?

Comment: see @Grizzly on how to implement the Timer solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Threading.Thread.Sleep(0)
```

This will cause the working thread to yield the rest of it's current timeslice which will reduce the cpu usage quite a bit. However you should consider whether you really nead busy waiting for the time or if you could get away with setting a timer to count down the difference between the current time and the expected time, e.g.:

```
            var t = new System.Timers.Timer((DateTime.Now - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds);
        t.Elapsed = DoSomething;
        t.Start();
```

Comment: so if I'm reading that correctly that creates a timer in milliseconds of the difference between the two times, and does something once the timer has elapsed? I apologize, I've never had to use a timer before.

Comment: yes, that is exactly the intended behaviour (of course this code is c#, so there are small syntactic differences when using it in vb.net, but other then that...)

Comment: of course, wow, thanks a lot for your help. You taught me some good stuff in a short time.

Answer (score 1):

> checking the systems clock to see if it's equal to a certain time.

There are two "correct" ways to do this:

1. Build a normal app that doesn't care what time it is, and set it up in windows as a schedule task.
2. Check the time *once* and calculate how long until the desired time.  Then set up a timer to wait for that exact duration.

Under no circumstance should you keep polling the system clock for something like this that will just run once.

Comment: based on the code sample in the question, I'd say option 2 is more correct! And I've often used this method myself.