# While loop causes the app to go slow? Any idea why?

Tags: vb.net, loops, performance

I have a simple code that looks up a text file, reads the line of text, splits the string by semi-colons and then posts the results.

After it has done this, I have created a really simple while loop to waste 10 seconds before going for it again.... here is the code:

```
Private Sub checkTemps()
    While Abort = False
        Try
            fileReader = New StreamReader(directory.Text & "currentTemp.dat")
            rawData = fileReader.ReadLine()
            fileReader.Close()
            Dim dataArray() As String
            dataArray = rawData.Split(";")
            updateOutput("1", dataArray(0), dataArray(1))
            updateOutput("2", dataArray(2), dataArray(3))
            updateOutput("3", dataArray(4), dataArray(5))
            updateOutput("4", dataArray(6), dataArray(7))
            stpWatch.Start()
            While stpWatch.Elapsed.Seconds < 10 And Abort = False
                pollInterval(stpWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds)
            End While
            stpWatch.Stop()
            stpWatch.Reset()
        Catch ex As Exception
            msgbox("oops!")
        End Try
    End While
    closeOnAbort()
End Sub
```

But when it gets to the "time-wasting" loop - it seems to slow the whole application down? And I can't work out why!

So a couple of questions... is there a better way to do all this? and second - can anyone spot a problem?

All the other commands seem to run fine - there isn't much else to this app. I have another program that updates the dat file with the values, this is simply a client side app to output the temperatures.

Any help would be appreciated.

Andrew

---

More info:

I should explain what the pollInterval sub does!

```
Private Delegate Sub pollIntervalDelegate(ByVal value As Integer)
Private Sub pollInterval(ByVal value As Integer)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim upbd As New pollIntervalDelegate(AddressOf pollInterval)
        Me.Invoke(upbd, New Object() {value})
    Else
        ProgressBar1.Value = value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: See also, on a related note, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664526/loop-to-check-time-in-vb-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is a very tight loop continually calling `pollInterval`. This will tie up the application until the loop condition is met.

You should use the [`Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332371%28VS.71%29.aspx) method to pause this thread for the required amount of time.

If you want to show the progress (as per your update) you could put the `Sleep` into the loop and sleep for 1 second (or half a second?) at a time:

```
        While stpWatch.Elapsed.Seconds < 10 And Abort = False
            Sleep(1000)      <-- NOT 100% sure of the syntax here,
                                 but the time is specified in milliseconds
            pollInterval(stpWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds)
        End While
```

Comment: What would you suggest?

I want to be able to show the remaining time before the next update using a progress bar... is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You should go with

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds);
```

Comment: But I want to show the length of time until the next refresh... if I put the thread to sleep - I won't be able to show this - will I?

Comment: You'll need to define a update interval; Add a `Thread.Sleep(1000)` inside your `while` loop and it will wait for a second before every screen update

Comment: So you mean - While stpWatch.Elapsed.Seconds < 10 And Abort = False | pollInterval(stpWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds) | Thread.Sleep(1000) | End While - ?